# How to add variable from nc1 to nc2 file without deleting/removing the variables in nc2?

Tags: netcdf, cdo-climate, nco, ncdf4

I have two kinds of variables in two different nc files. The dimension and other things are same, I just have to add one more variable in the existing nc file, How can I do this (using CDO or R or any other)

I used the command line (`cdo selvar,varname in.nc out.nc`) but it doesn't help. This command does work but deletes the existing variables. Any suggestions on how can I add new variables without deleting the variable inside the nc file?
Many thanks.

Comment: your question isn't very clear, do you mean you want to add the variable in nc1 to the file nc2?  Would a command such as cdo cat nc1 nc2 output.nc do what you want?  please clarify the question to make it clearer...

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I have two nc files 'aaa.nc' and 'bbb.nc'. aaa.nc file have variable name xxx, and bbb.nc file has variable yyy. Now, I want to copy yyy variable to aaa.nc (from bbb.nc). This means, I want both variables xxx and yyy to appear in aaa.nc file. Hope I make my question clear. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The NCO solution is

ncks -A -v yyy bbb.nc aaa.nc

as documented [here](https://nco.sf.net/nco.html#apn).

Comment: oops, yes, apologies - nco answer deleted in my response - thanks for pointing out my error

Answer (score 3):

From your comment of clarification, I think the `cdo` command you need is `cat`

```
cdo cat aaa.nc bbb.nc output.nc
```

This will concatenate the fields in `bbb.nc` to the ones in `aaa.nc` and put the result in `output.nc`